# Copying string without strcpy using pointers

Tags: c, arrays, string

I'm trying to copy a string str into str using pointers. i think this can be achieved using a single pointer itself. whenever i run my code im getting str1 to display but with excessive unwanted garbage characters. please help. provide some insights

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
  char str[10];
  char str1[10];
  printf("Enter a string");
  scanf("%s",str);
  char *p;
  char *q;
  int len=0,i=0;
  p=&str;
  q=&str;

  while (*p!='\0')
  {
    len=len+1;
    p=p+1;
  }

  printf("%d",len);
  printf("\n");

  while (len>0)
  {
    str1[i]=*q;
    len=len-1;
  }

  printf("%s",str1);
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you are missing a NULL-terminator in the destination string

Comment: @KamilCuk Not if the intent is to learn how things like `strcpy` work.

Comment: @VladRusu strings in C are not NULL terminated. They are zero terminated. NULL has a very specific meaning in the C language.

Comment: @P__J__ True. Forgot about the fact that NULL is most often defined as `void *`. But having the value 0 makes me usually use these terms interchangeably.

Comment: @VladRusu not they are not. One is the pointer type another is an integer.

Comment: @P__J__ Yeah, I know. What I'm trying to say is that I usually don't take their type into account when using the terms :) But I know the difference.

Answer (score 0):

`str1[i]` is always the same element because you never increment `i`. Thus all the other elements remain untouched and there is never an opportunity for the null terminator of `q` to be copied over.

Then, when you print it, the program has undefined behaviour.

It would probably be better to loop `i` from `0` to `len`.

You should also consider initialising your arrays with `= {}`, so that they contain nulls in the first place.

Furthermore, your `scanf` is extraordinarily unsafe as it performs no bounds checking.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have an example:

```
char *mystrcpy(char *dest, const char *src)
{
    char *saveddest = dest;
    while(*src)
    {
        *dest++ = *src++;
    }
    *dest = 0;
    return saveddest;
}
```

or

```
char *two_in_one_strcpy_strlen(char *dest, const char *src, size_t *len)
{
    char *saveddest = dest;

    *len = 0;
    while(*src)
    {
        *dest++ = *src++;
        *len++;
    }
    *dest = 0;
    return saveddest;
}
```